df and du reports vastly different results
I understand that this question has been asked before. But I couldn't find a very satisfactory answer, so asking again here, sorry.
So my root filesystem is ext3, df shows there is only 3.7G left. but du shows only 3.5G is used.  lsof shows there are only 3 dangling files that are very small.
what else can I check?
localhost:~ # df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                            63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               96G  168K   96G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               63G  364M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                               63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                           40G   35G  3.7G  91% /

localhost:~ # du -sh -x /
3.5G    /

PRSapHana:~ # lsof -a +L1 /
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK    NODE NAME
xrdp-chan  1024 root    6w   REG    8,2       67     0 2076767 /root/xrdp-chansrv.log (deleted)
gnome-she 22802 root   23r   REG    8,2    24436     0 2076894 /root/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gnome-she 22802 root   33r   REG    8,2    32768     0 2076896 /root/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-33d982e0.log (deleted)


Huh... make sure to run du as root, to catch any files that aren't readable to your user.  Otherwise, dumpe2fs is a good place to look.  Why are you running ext3, anyways? ext4 is much more used now.

@CalumMcConnell thanks for the comment. Yes, I ran du as root.  server was built long time ago by someone else, that's why ext3 is used, and we have no reason to change that.  I'll look into dumpe2fs, thanks.

The problem is caused by mounting another device onto a non-empty folder.
In my case, there is a large file in /mnt, say 30GB.
Say I mount a portable hard drive onto /mnt, the original files in /mnt would be hidden.
df would still consider these files. but du won't.

a tricky puzzle... maybe if I'd have seen the second device, i'd have spotted it
